# How can fill the user id field with auth user on creation of resource?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-nova

I'm sure there must be a very simple way to do this - I would like to fill the user_id field on my resource with the authenticated user's id whenever a new instance of the resource is created.

In the store() method of my Resource model I have:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $resource = Resource::create($input);
    $resource->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    return $resource;

    return 'Resource added.';
}
```

This works through a post API route, however whenever I add a new resource instance through Nova dashboard, it does not add the Auth user id. I'm guessing this because Nova doesn't use that Resource controller that I have set out?

I would appreciate suggestions!

Comment: maybe somewhere in the dashboard you can tell nova to use this controller

Answer (score 3):

Working on the assumption that you have relationship method `User::resources()` the following should work:

```php
return $request->user()->resources()->create($request->all());
```

The way you have it doesn't work because you didn't save the resource after associating user with it.

Comment: This is the right way if you have proper relationship. You can also do directly `Auth::user()->resources()->create($request->all())` if you are sure that you have a logged-in user on execution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Nova yet, but since its also laravel and most likely Eloquent ORM I can tell the following.

In these two lines you've set the `user_id` but you haven't persisted the change:

```
$resource->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
return $resource;
```

You should add this line to save the changes you've done:

```
$resource->save();
```

As an alternative you could add the value already into your `$input` array:

```
$input = $request->all();
$input["user_id"] = Auth::user()->id;
$resource = Resource::create($input);
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but I think the alternative you suggested was a neater way of writing what I had initially, so thanks for that.

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20896605. That request is way too broad, and such be closed as such. No other person but the OP would be able to "fix" the question via editing, therefore editing is absolutely wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I just created an ResourceObserver. Saved the Auth()->user->id with the created method.

Registered the ResourceObserver to AppServiceProvider and NovaServiceProvider.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/#resource-events

Answer (score 0):

In the model class, add function like this:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    $this->user_id = auth()->id();
    parent::save($options);
}
```

Just be carefull if you tend to use save in any other scenario so you don't overwrite existing user_id.